# Why doesn't this event unbind using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have seen similar questions but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.  The dropdown is shown after an ajax call completes successfully then I want to hide it when a user clicks anywhere.  I would like to remove the event though because there is no need to hide it if it is already hidden.

```
        dropDown.slideDown('fast');
        $(document).bind('click.test', function() {
            alert('click');
            dropDown.slideUp('fast');
            $(document).unbind('click.test');
        });
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [`one` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead.